# PHP - htmlentities - Czech language issues

Tags: php, html, mysql

Currently having issues with the translation script handling special characts mainly from Czech language.
A administration is allowed to translate my platform from english to it's own language, however when they do some of the characters are getting stored as ? instead of the html entities.

For example the following word: nepřetržitě
Is getting stored as: nep?etržit?

When saving to the database I use htmlentities(value) before inserting.
What should I do to get this working?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: _“When saving to the database I use htmlentities(value) before inserting.”_ - that is wrong to begin with. Don’t _mess_ with the data at this point, store it in its original form. Applying any function like this should only happen when you _output_ the data into a specific context.

Comment: Dear CBroe, thanks for your quick reply, I removed the htmlentities function and insert the data plain, however it still gets saved with ? instead of the real character.
When I try to store the same data directly in SQL it gives me a format string error.
Looks like in this case Codeigniter is also doing something with the data before saving.